# Как можно оценить суровость выполненного запроса?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

Например, есть некоторый сервис, который время от времени выполняет запросы и нужно определить насколько запрос был "тяжелым".

По каким критериям это можно оценить?

Первое, что пришло на ум- это замерить загрузку процессора на SQL Server до и во время выполнения запроса.

По каким критериям еще можно понять, что запрос оказался тяжелым и мог негавтивно сказаться на работу других пользователей с БД?

Собственно, это нужно для программы балансировки нагрузки, что бы выполнять тяжелые запросы в наиболее подходящее время. Собственно, не помешал бы минимальный пример, как эту статистику можно получить из когда программы.

Comment: MySql или MS SQL используете?

Comment: Можно воспользоваться специализированными средствами [мониторинга и настройки производительности](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms189081(v=sql.90).aspx), которые поставляются в комплекте с MS SQL. Трассировки, планы запросов, профилировщик, мониторинг использования ресурсов и многое другое.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Тяжесть зависит от плана выполнения. План выполнения может меняться в зависимости от статистики по таблицам. Статистика может устаревать и порождать неверные планы. Так что "тяжесть" - величина непостоянная.

Кроме того, в SQL Server есть кэш данных, и запрос, выбирающий данные их кэша, ес-но будет выдавать меньше физических чтений с диска. Поэтому при замерах стоит смотреть на количество логических чтений, а не только на количество физических.

Грубо можно оценить, замерив время и IO напрямую:

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
SET STATISTICS IO ON

запрос
```

Выполнить несколько раз, отбросить максимальное и минимальное значение по CPU, по остальным - взять среднее.

Показатели IO будут зависеть от плана, так что они при последовательных выполнениях не поменяются. Для воспроизведения промаха кэша - почистите его вызовом `CHECKPOINT; DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS;`

Из .NET значения статистики можно получить, выставлением свойства [`sqlConnection.StatisticsEnabled = true`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.statisticsenabled(v=vs.110).aspx) + вызовом [`sqlConnection.RetrieveStatistics()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.retrievestatistics(v=vs.110).aspx)

---

Что делать с "плохим" запросом - достаточно обширный вопрос. Минимальный набор действий

- пересчитать статистику для используемых таблиц(обязательно, иначе есть шанс бороть несуществующую проблему!)
- получить свежий план выполнения
- если план плохой - оптимизировать запрос, индексы или структуру базы

Что точно не стоит делать - это править SQL наугад. Оптимизация SQL - достаточно простой процесс, но при этом нужно точно представлять механизм выполнения запросов SQL Server, иначе можно получить кучу скрытых проблем :)

Comment: А я это могу в коде считать и получить эту статистику?

Comment: @iluxa1810 дописал

Comment: а обязательно вперед каждый запросом помещать SET'ы если поставить sqlConnection.StatisticsEnabled = true ?

Comment: @iluxa1810 нет, их кода сеты можно вообще не писать (вроде бы)

Answer (score 8):

Объективный критерий - это замеры статистики при выполнении запроса, PashaPash вам про них уже [написал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/707398/178779). Но недостаток такого метода заключается в том, что он позволяет только измерять запросы, но не говорит что надо изменить.

Поэтому я часто использую альтернативный вариант - просмотр плана выполнения запроса. Его можно получить командой EXPLAIN - но лучше пользоваться соответствующей кнопкой в SQL Mangement Studio и смотреть графический план.

Если вы делаете запрос на ограниченное количество строк (используете конструкцию TOP) - то главными врагами будут **Sort** и **Hash Join**. Sort полностью вычитывает входные строки перед тем как начать выдавать хоть что-нибудь на выход, Hash Join то же самое делает со своим вторым входом. Оба варианта не позволяют получить от конструкции TOP нормального ускорения для запроса.

Также маркером что что-то пошло не так, может выступать конструкция **Merge Join**, а также упомянутые ранее Sort и Hash Join. Эти операции вполне нормальны для сложных аналитических запросов - но для постоянно используемых запросов их в плане быть не должно.

Далее, следует проверить операции класса Scan (**Table Scan**, **Clustered Index Scan** и **Index Scan**). Есть шанс, что оптимизатор запросов не нашел подходящего индекса и просматривает таблицу целиком. Тем не менее, если ваш запрос как раз и запрашивает таблицу целиком - это нормально :-) Также полные сканы обычно неплохо ускоряются при наличии ограничения TOP (но только если они идут по первому, "верхнему" пути в соединении).

Чтобы отличить "хороший" скан от плохого, можно посмотреть на его параметры. Если там ничего не указано или указан только Predicate - это полное сканирование таблицы. При указании Range сканируются записи попавшие в некоторый диапазон - тут надо смотреть что это за диапазон, чем он задается и сколько там записей. При указании Prefix сканируются записи, у которых совпадает часть ключа.

Также можно просто посмотреть на ожидаемое количество строк.

Comment: А я могу эту статистику собрать в прикладной программе на C# или только в Managment Studio эти данные можно получить? Если первое, то не помешал бы минимальный пример.

Comment: Nested Loops тоже обычно плохо, особенно в запросах на потенциально больших объемах (SQL Server любит делать Nested Loops вместо Merge / Hash при устаревшей статистике, тем самым убивая производительность), так что можно обобщить до "любой джойн" - зло :)

Comment: @PashaPash ну, этот случай на самом деле раскрыт в сканах :-)

Comment: @iluxa1810 план запроса можно получить в прикладной программе на C#, но нет никакого смысла поступать таким образом. Это именно информация для "посмотреть", а не для автоматического анализа.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, не, план запроса мне не особо нужен. Меня интересует фактические показатели. Например, как его процесс выполнения оказал влияние на сам сервер в целом. Т.е CPU под потолок ушел, взаимоблокировки появились и юзеры начали отвалится по таймауту.

Comment: @iluxa1810 так меня-то почему вы об этом спрашиваете?

Comment: @PavelMayorov знак вопроса был лишним=(

Answer (score 4):

Приведу два варианта.

1. Программный. Полистав интернет, найдя и модифицировав сложные запросы я сделал себе такие выборки (они показывают тяжёлые запросы, а не конкретный запрос, но как правило свой остаётся какое-то время в кеше)

   ```
   select * from (
   select (select text from sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle)) tx, max(last_execution_time) tm    from sys.dm_exec_query_stats  group by sql_handle ) t where tx not like '%CREATE PROCEDURE%'  order by 1


   SELECT text, cp.objtype, cp.size_in_bytes FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS cp CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(cp.plan_handle) st WHERE cp.cacheobjtype = N'Compiled Plan' AND cp.objtype IN(N'Adhoc', N'Prepared') AND cp.usecounts = 1 ORDER BY cp.size_in_bytes DESC OPTION (RECOMPILE);


   select  (select text from sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle)) tx, * from sys.dm_exec_requests

   SELECT objtype AS [CacheType]
   , count_big(*) AS [Total Plans]
   , sum(cast(size_in_bytes as decimal(18,2)))/1024/1024 AS [Total MBs]
   , avg(usecounts) AS [Avg Use Count]
   , sum(cast((CASE WHEN usecounts = 1 THEN size_in_bytes ELSE 0 END) as decimal(18,2)))/1024/1024 AS [Total MBs — USE Count 1]
   , sum(CASE WHEN usecounts = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Total Plans — USE Count 1]
   FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans
   GROUP BY objtype
   ORDER BY [Total MBs — USE Count 1] DESC
   ```
2. Вручную можно открыть Activity Monitor. В ранних версиях (2005, 2008) он находится в корне `Management` в Sql Management Studio, в поздних версиях он в контекстном меню "сервера" в Sql Management Studio.