# Есть ли разница в скорости выполнения запросов.

Tags: sql

Вот два запроса которые выдают одинаковый результат. 
Пример 1

```
select rt.name, rd.position_on_route, p.name , p.address, p.cust_id
from route_head_translation rt
inner join route_detail rd on rt.translatable_id = rd.route_head_id and rt.locale = 'ru' and rd.deleted_at is null
inner join  pos p on p.id = rd.pos_id and p.deleted_at is null  and p.employee_id ='2661A7B8-96AF-4C11-98E5-A4CD45C05BBE' 
order by rt.name , rd.position_on_route
```

Пример 2

```
select rt.name, rd.position_on_route, p.name , p.address, p.cust_id
from route_head_translation rt
inner join route_detail rd on rt.translatable_id = rd.route_head_id 
inner join  pos p on p.id = rd.pos_id 
where rt.locale = 'ru' and rd.deleted_at is null
and p.deleted_at is null  and p.employee_id ='2661A7B8-96AF-4C11-98E5-A4CD45C05BBE' 
order by rt.name , rd.position_on_route
```

Вопросы.
1. Есть ли между ними разница в скорости их выполнения ? 
2. Какой способ предпочтительней использовать ?

P.S. Лично моё размышление . Мне кажется 1 первый запрос должен работать быстрее , потому что на этапе соединение по условию уменьшится количество данных которые нужно соединить. Я так же не исключаю, sql сам решает когда что ему делать и в какой последовательности в не зависимости от семантики.

Comment: В соседнем [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/707391/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0) как раз обсуждают

Comment: Зависит от СУБД и его оптимизатора. но в большинстве СУБД сейчас план выполнения при задании условий в ON (при inner join) и WHERE ничем не отличается. И ни одна современная СУБД не выполняет запрос в том порядке, как пишут во всяких теоретических статьях которые написаны в терминологии работы с множествами. _Всегда_ смотрите реальный план выполнения с помощью explain и делайте выводы

Comment: Похоже я могу сделать вывод. Нет смыла смотреть на семантику, нужно лишь опираться на explain.